# Getting latest App version from Google PlayStore in case of mutiple apk's uploaded

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have uploaded multiple APK's for my app on Playstore to support it across all devices.

Now the issue is when I get my Playstore version using the following code it returns "Varies with device".

String playStoreUrl = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + mContext.getPackageName();

```
            //It retrieves the latest version by scraping the content of current version from play store at runtime
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(playStoreUrl)).get();
            mAppStoreVersion = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue
                    ("itemprop","softwareVersion").first().text();
```

mAppStoreVersion is "Varies with device". Is there any other way of getting the latest app version from Playstore?

Comment: What are the differences for each APK? Do they vary just by which API level they support? Or are there other differences as well?

Comment: There are other differences as well. I use native libraries, so the variation is also based on the CPU architecture (armabi, x86 etc). I publish different APK for every CPU architecture as it helps in reducing the app size considerably.

Comment: @Pareek Any change you discover how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the version as 'Varies with device', you may check your Google Play Publisher account. Google Play allows you to publish different APKs for your application. Each one targeted to different device configuration. Thus, each APK is an independent version of your application, but they share the same application listing on Google Play and must share the same package name and be signed with the same release key.

For more details, you may check the official [Google documentation for Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Comment: I have already published multiple APKs. My question here is , can i get the App version of my apk published for devices with API level greater than x?

Comment: This was not the question, we want to know how we can get it from the store independently.